# How do I reference an uninitialized global variable in a test?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to unit test some of my code, but my code refers to this library that I don't have direct access to. My code will have access to it when run, but not at compile time. In this example, the library code is called `setup`.  I'm not using webpack or anything, just TS node.

prod code:

```
declare let setup: any;

setup.rest = (): void => { // this signature can't change

}
```

test code:

```
import "jasmine";

describe("App", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        setup = {};
    })

    it("should have a rest function", () => {
        setup.rest();
    });
});
```

I am using Jasmine as a test runner.  When I run my tests, I get this error:

> ReferenceError: setup is not defined

How I get my test to initialize this `setup` variable and share it with my production code?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you want to initialize the function `super`

you can add a spy her.

```
const setupSpy = TestBed.get(setup);
setupSpy.rest.and.returnValue(add here object/variable to return)
```

Comment: but the prod code would error if it's run first. That set up doesn't exist in the context of the test. How do i prevent the prod code from running before the test?